# Select all values with newest date

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table where every day values of different YouTube videos are crawled.
Now I would like to output all values which have the newest date.

`` SELECT * FROM `youtubeData` WHERE date = MAX(date); ``

That means I want to have a filtered output of all records with the date 28.06.20 at the end.

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
selet ytd.*
from youtubedata ytd
where ytd.date = (select max(ytd2.date) from youtubedata ytd2);
```

With an index on `(date)`, this should also have very good performance.